# Help in identifying low speed image transmission protocol over RF

Tags: audio, demodulation, frequency-modulation, radio, software-defined-radio

In the seventies I worked for [Muirhead](https://rochesteravionicarchives.co.uk/organisations/muirhead-co) on press fax machines that used to transmit pictures over radio and landline as I recall two FM systems were used a carrier 800 Hz modulated +- 150 Hz and 1900Hz +- 400 Hz.

I have recently found software to get my old [ICOM PCR1000](https://www.universal-radio.com/catalog/widerxvr/1002.html) communication receiver going again on windows 10 and am picking up a strong signal on 162.800 kHz that appears to be the former system .

Is there any software available that would demodulate it and can anyone identify it?

Comment: The only thing related to ICOM that I can find is this: https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Next_Generation_Digital_Narrowband_(NXDN)  There might be some useful pointers there.

Comment: I can't say that it rings any bells apart from something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_picture_transmission). In the sense that probably the image is unfolded row-major and then sent over with suitable markers. If you could capture a "session", it might help with decoding it.

Comment: I notice with a better antenna there are similar signals on 164 kH, it is definitely not pictures I know what pictures sound like!, I believe it may well be text connected with the internet over phone line service (I get my internet via optical cable much better)